# Grails 2.5.6 strange filters behavior

Tags: grails, grails-2.5

I have `Grails 2.5.6` application using `Spring Security Grails plugin` and there is a filter in the application to check something if exists continue normally if not must go to the controller `Country`, action `countryAndCity` , the URL before accessing the filter is **`https://localhost:8443/MyApp/login/auth`** after executing the filter the redirect URL is **`http://localhost:8080//countries/countryAndCity`**,

What is making this strange behavior in the URLs? below are the 2 filters executing in this phase :

SwitchToHTTPSFilters:

```
def filters = {

    // to redirect to HTTPS for the below actions
    all(controller: 'users|login|countries', action: 'create|auth|*', actionExclude: 'logout') {
        before = {


            if (!request.isSecure()) {
           def url = "https://" + request.serverName + ':8443' + request.forwardURI

                redirect(url: url, permanent: true)
                return false
            }
        }
        after = {Map model ->
        }
        afterView = {Exception e ->
        }
    }
}
```

SetCountryAndCityFirstFilters:

```
// for the Users controller set country and city first
 def filters = {
    all(controller: 'users', action: 'create') {
        before = {
            if (session.countryAndCity == null) {      
                session.forwardToURI = request.forwardURI
                redirect(controller: "countries", action: "countryAndCity")
            }
        }
        after = {Map model ->
        }
        afterView = {Exception e ->
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I must guess, I would say that Spring Security overrides/overwrites your redirect, at least when you weren't logged in before calling the URL. After authentication Spring Security redirects you to the location it remembered.

Comment: @StefanRother-Stübs So why is that happening?

Comment: I don't really know. I'd like to pass the question to @burtbeckwith